# Hadoop correct tool when only processing small ( < 100mb) amounts of data?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hadoop

This is more a hypothetical question, although it does have some practical background..
I've been playing around with the idea of leveraging hadoop for some batch tasks that need to be done by an application i'm currently working on. (JEE 6 on JBoss 7)

specifically this would include text analysis of user generated input (e.g. trend recognition, occurrences) on the one hand and a batch of text files on the other hand (e.g. source code from a repository but let's leave that aside for now)

As I've started reading around i noticed that hadoop is primarily focused on huge sets of data (e.g. chunk size 100 mb) which makes sense to really get something out of this nifty thing called hdfs..

well basically I have two questions..

1. is hadoop the correct choice for doing this kind of work? i mean the basic wordcount example would already solve one of my business needs ..
2. considering the fact, that even a huge java project basically boils down to max. a few megabytes of text files, this still is so little data.. Could this actually be a problem when implementing or executing these tasks ?

Comment: changed the title to the real issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is definitely not the tool for the job for a multi-megabyte job.

For reference, the default block size of HDFS is 64MB, because it was determined roughly that any data smaller than that would involve greater spin-up overhead than was worth it for the parallelism provided by Hadoop. So, if your few megabytes job was run on Hadoop, it would only use one processor at a time, completely not using the parallelism of the platform.

The general rule of thumb is, if the entire data corpus can fit into the RAM of a single JVM, then you don't need Hadoop at all. Given that the available RAM of a basic production machine these days is on the order of several GB, then you should not consider Hadoop until you move to the multi-GB per day range of data sizes.

For a small task like that over text corpuses, there are natural language libraries in python that would probably be better suited, such as nltk. Of course, if it is just a word count you are looking for then any language will be fine, such as native python, or perl.

Comment: will mark this as accepted answer as it was exactly the information i was looking for. thanks fish =)